# Low drive space on c: partitions on clustered servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a 2 node cluster on Windows Server 2008 R2, with a SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn AG. Both C: partitions are running out of space.

Can I expand the C: partition on the secondary node, reboot, failover from the primary node to secondary and then expand the C: partition on the primary node? Is there a better way?

Also, I noticed the pagefile.sys on both servers are using a lot of space.  Each has a 72GB pagefile.  I am thinking of moving the pagefile to a different partition and leaving a small pagefile(1 gb) on C:.  I would start this option on the secondary server and then the primary, performing failovers as needed. Good idea or not?

Comment: You most certainly don't need a 72GB page file unless you're taking many full memory dumps.. in which case you have a larger issue than drive space. Save some space, give yourself an 8 GB PF and take back 64 GB. Also, the PF doesn't need to be on the c:\ volume since WS2008 w/hotfixes, so you're still good :)

Comment: I would recommend having a dedicated volume for the pagefile and set the size manually to 5 MB less than the total size of the volume. Changing the location of the pagefile will require a reboot to take affect. 

If you use TreeSizeFree where does it show the most space is being used on C:? C:\Windows\winsxs? You could perform a Disk Cleanup to get rid of old Windows Update files.

Do you have SQL Server installed on C:?

Comment: SQL server is not installed on C. I'll check out the above suggestions. Thanks.